# Thread.sleep() stopping my paint?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, graphics, jframe

I'm making a program that is trying to animate a card moving across the screen as if you actually drew it from a desk. Here is the code for the animating:

```
public void move(int x, int y) {
    int curX = this.x; //the entire class extends rectangle
    int curY = this.y;

    // animate the movement to place
    for (int i = curX; i > x; i--) {
        this.x = i;
    }

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

this rectangle object is inside of a panel inside of a jframe. for repainting the panel, i have this:

```
public void run() {
    while (Core.isRunning()) {
        gamePanel.repaint(); //panel in which my rectangle object is in

        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

this is a thread, repainting the gamePanel every 50 milliseconds.

Now, I realize this may not be the best way to do this sort of thing. if there is a better way to do this whole repainting thing, please inform me!

But, the problem i'm having is when i call the `move()` command for my rectangle, it goes through the thread, but the image isnt updating till the end, so it's just a jump from point a to the final location.

why is this happening? can anyone critique/improve my code? thanks!

Comment: You may want to look at [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) trial.

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you call `Thread.sleep()` in the [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) causing the GUI become unresponsive. To avoid this you may want to use [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead:

```
   Timer timer = new Timer(50, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(!stop) {
                gamePanel.repaint();
            } else {
                ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
            }
        }
    });
    timer.setRepeats(true);
    timer.setDelay(50);
    timer.start();
```

Where `stop` is a boolean flag that indicates the animation must stop.

Comment: i've implemented this as my refresh spot, and it still doesnt have the animation for the card... i added a thread.sleep(50) in my move() command, and have it print out the i variable, so it is moving, just no animations... do you know why?

Comment: @PulsePanda The point is don't use Thread.sleep() with swing. The Swing timer will execute every 50 millis (quite small amount of time BTW) untill the stop condition is reached.

Comment: so the `thread.sleep(50);` in my `move()` method in the for loop is causing this as well/

Comment: @PulsePanda I think so. You need to find a way to place animation without using Thread.sleep(). For instance using a Swing timer. Or you can research for combining [MouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) and [MouseMotionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseMotionListener.html). The whole point is don't block the *Event Dispatch Thread* with `Thread.sleep()` (or any time consuming task).

Comment: so how would i implement that in my move() for loop? i've been trying but cant get it to work

Answer (score -1):

Most probably, the `for`loop in method `move()` is running so fast you don't see any transitions. The simplest way to solve this is adding a sleep within the loop in the `move()` method, such as:

```
public void move(int x, int y) {
    int curX = this.x; //the entire class extends rectangle
    int curY = this.y;

    // animate the movement to place
    for (int i = curX; i > x; i--) {
        this.x = i;
        Thread.sleep(20); // Just experiment with other sleep amounts
    }
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

Regarding the repainting logic, it is generally inefficient to have a separate thread redraw everything at each cycle, mainly because you could be repainting things that haven't actually changed. It is usually more efficient to update only the things that change.

In a complex situation in which several shapes overlap each other, you would need to determine what changes and what doesn't, because if something doesn't move but is overlapped by something that does, you would need to update the overlapped shape as well to ensure it is drawn correctly. There are sofisticated algortihms that address just this problem, but if your scene does not have many shapes then it could be simpler to just redraw everything when something changes.

Comment: _Don't_ sleep on the EDT; _do_ see [*Concurrency in Swing*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) to [*How to Use Swing Timers*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Comment: I didn't say it was the correct thing to do, I just said it was the easiest fix possible. Having a separate thread update the object position is of course better.

Comment: I can see the appeal, but then you have to synchronize access to the shared location data.

Comment: *"I just said it was the easiest fix possible"*  By 'fix' DYM 'break'?  Very, *very* wrong answer.